# Display and hide actionButton based on 2 other actionButtons

Tags: r, shiny

Below I press the first `actionButton() "Show"` to display another `actionButton()` but I would like also a second `actionButton()` named `"Hide"` that will hide the `actionButton()` that is displayed after clicking the `"Show"`.

```
library(shiny)
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("button1", label = "Show"),
      actionButton("button1b", label = "Hide")

    ),
    mainPanel(
      # what should I write here?
      uiOutput("button2")
    )
  )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    output$button2 <- renderUI({
      actionButton("button2", label = "Press Button 2")
    })
  })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to put the second button inside a `conditionalPanel` and set a toggle to display/hide the panel. See working code below.

```
library(shiny)
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("button1", label = "Show"),
      actionButton("button1b", label = "Hide")
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # what should I write here?
      conditionalPanel(condition = "output.display",
                       actionButton("button2", label = "Press Button 2"))
    )
  )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  r <- reactiveValues(
    toggle = NULL
  )
  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    r$toggle = 1
  })
  observeEvent(input$button1b, {
    r$toggle = 0
  })
  output$display <- reactive({
    r$toggle
  })
  outputOptions(output, "display", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)  
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Another option is to dynamically insert and remove UI elements. But that option requires creation/destruction of UI elements every time the buttons are clicked. [See example here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html)

Comment: A third option is to use [shinyjs package](https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/).